# Flutter convert capitalized names to lowercase

Tags: flutter

The issue is that the backend has names that are all capitalized, for example RUBEN VAN BUREN. At the moment we show it like that in the app but it looks really out of place. We want to convert it to Ruben van Buren but we don't know how. We have to convert names from all over the world so Ruben Van buren is wrong, for example.

Does anyone had this problem before and knows a solution?

Comment: This question is incorrectly marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`namefully`](https://pub.dev/packages/namefully) package does support converting non-standard name cases.